# Projections on Hilbert spaces and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to solve the following question but I'm hopelessly lost.  My ideas are detailed below.

[image]

For part (i), I can obviously get $$E((1- \pi(1))\pi(1)) = 0 \implies E(\pi^2(1)) = E(\pi(1)) $$ and we also know that $0 \leq E( (1-\pi(1)^2) = 1 - 2E(\pi(1)) + E(\pi^2(1)) = 1 - E(\pi(1) \implies E(\pi(1)) \leq 1$

I have absolutely no idea how to get a strict inequality on the lower bound at $0$ for part (i), which I know is equivalent to showing that $P(\pi(1) \ne 0) > 0$.  I have tried everything I can think of, which is, truly disappointingly, absolutely useless.  I know that since $1$ is NOT in the closure of $\mathcal{G}$, we must have that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $E(1-g)^2 \ge \epsilon \quad \forall g \in \mathcal{G}$ and obviously $E(\pi(1)g) = 0$ as well.

I thought that maybe using the projection of $1$ onto the closure of $\mathcal{G}$ might be helpful, but this has also been useless for me.

I don't know how to do (ii) either, but I was thinking of trying to apply Holder's inequality - again this is (somewhat) useless: $$E(\pi(1) \pi(H))^2 \leq E(\pi^2(H)) E(\pi^2(1)) = E(\pi^2(H)) E(\pi(1)) $$ I don't know how to "get rid" of of the $\pi(1)$ in the LHS.

(iii) is also painful for me, because we know that $\pi(1) = \arg \min_{Z \in \mathcal{G}^\perp} E(Z-1)^2$ and therefore $$\text{Var}(\pi(1)/E(\pi(1)) = \frac{E(\pi^2(1)) - E(\pi(1))^2}{E(\pi(1))^2} = \frac{E(\pi(1))(1 - E(\pi(1)))}{E(\pi(1))^2} = \frac{1 - E(\pi(1))}{E(\pi(1))} \\ = \frac{E(1-\pi(1))^2}{E(\pi(1))} \leq \frac{E(Z-1)^2}{E(\pi(1))} = \text{Var(Z)}/E(\pi(1))\\ \forall Z \in \{D \in \mathcal{G}^\perp: E(D) = 1\}$$ but this does not give us what we want since $1/E(\pi(1)) \geq 1$.  Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (i), you essentially said the answer yourself. Just note that $\pi_G(1) + \pi_{G^\perp}(1) = 1$, and you will see that if $\pi_{G^\perp}(1) = 0$ a.s., then $\pi_G(1) = 1$ which means $1$ was in $G$.

For part (ii), you again did the necessary calculation; just substitute $\pi(H)$ instead of $\pi(1)$ to get $E[(1 - \pi(1)) \pi(H)] = 0 $

For part (iii) you use  part (ii), note that for any $D \in \mathcal{D}$, you can write the inequality in part (ii) as

$E[D^2] \geq \frac{1}{E[\pi(1)]}$ so you can get your desired inequality by subtracting 1 from both sides.

Comment: Thanks so much, again.  I'm horrible at functional analysis it would seem - I should've realized a lot of these details

Comment: No worries; this one was mostly a "linear algebra" question; I did the question by basically working in R^2. Projections in this space is not that much different than projections in R^n. (Finite vs infinite dimensions of course can cause issues) Also, hopefully this is not a breach of privacy, but you have been posting many questions, which means you are working very hard for presumably your prelim. With all the hard work you put in, I hope it goes well! Good job studying! (Also some questions (like the convex one you posted are just too hard so dont worry too much. about those :D))

Comment: Thank you...this is really nice of you to say. Also thanks for your help on a (shockingly large) number of these questions.  Hopefully the convex one is atypical because I'll fail for sure if they have a few of those on it.